# ordering by another table column mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, `messages` and `thread` messages is the main table and thread is where I keep the conversation between two users. I want to select only from `messages` table and order by `thread_id` from `thread` table. I am using the below sql but it doesn't order as I want it.

My aim is when new message is inserted to `thread` table make the parent message in `messages` table appear at the top. Does anyone have any idea?

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM messages AS m 
     JOIN thread AS t 
          ON t.thread_id = m.id 
WHERE ( m.to_user = ?  
    AND m.deleted != ?
    AND m.del2 != ?)
    OR
    (m.from_user = ? 
     AND m.conversation = 'true'
     AND m.deleted != ? 
     AND m.del2 != ?) 
ORDER BY t.thread_id desc);
```

**messages table**

```
id      to_user  from_user      message      is_read     deleted     del2   conversation
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1        user1     user2         hi mark,      true                         true
2        user3     user4         wass up yo?   true                         true
3        user1     user3         blah blah
```

**thread table**

```
thread_id      thread_to_user  thread_from_user      thread_message     thread_message_id  thread_is_read
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

1              user2           user1               hi there,                    1            1
2              user1           user2               hey, wassup                  1            1
3              user2           user1               not much, hw u doin          1            1
4              user1           user2               doing great and you?         1            0
5              user3           user4               heyyyy                       2            1
6              user4           user3               hi, u coming?                2            0
```

What I am expecting when echoing the row:

```
id      to_user  from_user      message      is_read     deleted     del2   conversation
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 2        user3     user4         wass up yo?   true                         true
 1        user1     user2         hi mark,      true                         true
 3        user1     user3         blah blah
```

Comment: To order by thread_id, it should figure in your results. So, just add it in your `SELECT` and it should order as expected

Comment: The 3rd record in your `Message` table which has `id=3`, which record does it relate to in your `thread` table?

Comment: @Edper between those users no conversation has started yet so when user1 sees the message and replies the reply goes in to `thread` table having `thread_message_id = 3`

Comment: Check my answer below @user3006683. I hope that's what you're looking far otherwise kindly tell me where i miss it ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(id), to_user,from_user,
 message, is_read, conversation
FROM messages
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT thread_id, thread_message_id
  FROM messages m
  LEFT JOIN thread t
  ON m.id = t.thread_message_id
) tbl
ON messages.id = tbl.thread_message_id
ORDER BY tbl.thread_id DESC
```

See [fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67f88c/6)

You could put your `WHERE` inside the subquery, like:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT(id), to_user,from_user,
  message, is_read, conversation
  FROM messages
  LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT thread_id, thread_message_id
   FROM messages m
   LEFT JOIN thread t
   ON m.id = t.thread_message_id
   WHERE ( m.to_user = ?  
   AND m.deleted != ?
   AND m.del2 != ?)
   OR
  (m.from_user = ? 
    AND m.conversation = true
    AND m.deleted != ? 
    AND m.del2 != ?) 
  ) tbl
  ON messages.id = tbl.thread_message_id
  ORDER BY tbl.thread_id DESC
```

See [Fiddle Demo with WHERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14794/4)

Update (Using `MAX()` with subquery)

```
SELECT id, to_user, from_user, message, is_read, conversation
FROM (
 SELECT m.id, max(t.thread_id) thread_id, m.to_user,m.from_user,m.message, m.is_read,    m.conversation
 FROM messages m
 LEFT JOIN thread t on(t.thread_message_id = m.id)
  WHERE ( m.to_user = 'user1'  
  AND m.deleted != true
 AND m.del2 != true)
 OR
 (m.from_user = 'user3' 
  AND m.conversation = true
  AND m.deleted != true 
  AND m.del2 != true) 
 GROUP BY m.id
 ORDER BY thread_id desc
 ) tbl
```

[See Other Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66a07/10)

Comment: where do I put the `WHERE` ?

Comment: Okay I tried your answer but Somehow it doesn't order it still. Even if I insert new row the row the parent row associcated with that message_id doesn't come on the top.

Comment: @user3006683 : I think I over analyzed this one. I utilized Salim Mujawar's answer but with changes like the `GROUP BY` and making it as a `subquery`.

Comment: thanks now it works, would it be possible to show on top if new message arrives in which a conversation hasn't been started yet like a message with `id=3` on the messages table?

Comment: @user3006683. Try changing the `ORDER BY` to this : `ORDER BY m.conversation asc, thread_id desc`

Comment: oh yeah it shows the new message on top now  but the other order doesn't work if I send another reply. The message with no conversation is staying at the top always.

Comment: Yes, that would be the case the message with no thread will be on top using `ORDER BY m.conversation asc, thread_id desc`. But that's what you were asking earlier? That is, the new message would be on top that has no thread yet, right? Or did i miss u on this? ;-)

Comment: oh yeah actually that is what I asked. I was just wondering if new message is sent then it goes to top then if another reply was sent that goes to top making the new message go one down. Thanks anyway for your help, you helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

please refer the below query and the fiddle example

```
select m.id, max(t.thread_id) thread_id, m.to_user,m.from_user,m.message, m.is_read, m.conversation
from messages m
left join thread t on(t.thread_message_id = m.id)
group by t.thread_message_id
order by thread_id desc;
```

[fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67f88c/27)